# Virtual Reality Lightning Component for Salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

I would like to ask if you can incorporate VR in a lightning component or a Lightning App?. I am planning to create a virtual tours and would like to ask a developers p.o.v for this kind of idea?. Thank you.

Comment: what technology do you want to insert into the component?

Comment: its like a virtual tour,  most common example is google streetview. but VR will take place if you put of course a VR like cardboard, oculus etc., i asked this question because of the curiosity of what can be the limit of the component if this will be pushed through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with at least the 3D view.

I did a test some time ago with a 3D scene built with Unity 3D. I was able to render it with WebGL in an iframe inside Lightning Experience.

I am not sure about the VR part because it requires the ability to go full screen and this might be blocked by Lightning.

Comment: So the fullscreen will be blocked?, can you elaborate more sir?. I need to explain this to my teammate so he can understand more. Thank you.

Comment: I haven't tried it so I cannot be 100% positive about whether it is feasible in Lightning. What I can tell you for sure is that VR requires full screen access.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a widely sought feature in most SF orgs. Your best bet is trying to hook up with the industry standard [WebVR](https://webvr.rocks/).

Comment: I see, but will there any limits regarding the usage of this? I saw matterport sdk to render a full blown 360 model of a house. I would like to do that also. will there any conflicts regarding that?